# Using a template instance type within a template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

If I were to write a template

```
  template<class T>
class myTemplate{
...
};
```

is there a syntax in either C++11 or C++14 which would allow me to identify a type of `myTemplate<T>*` within the actual template declaration?

For instance, what is the correct syntax for writing something like

```
template <class T>
class myTemplate{
...
void myTemplate(myTemplate<T>*, int);
....
};
```

TIA

Vinod

Comment: Constructors don't have a return type. Drop `void`; `myTemplate(myTemplate<T>*, int);` is a valid declaration of a constructor of `myTemplate`. I'm not sure I quite understand what it is you have a problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `myTemplate<T>` you can refer the same type (as method argument) as `myTemplate<T>` or simply as `myTemplate`. This is true also referring pointers to this type.

So you can write

```
 myTemplate (myTemplate<T> *, int) {}
```

but also

```
 myTemplate (myTemplate *, int) {}
```

When you want refer to `myTemplate<T>` for different `T` types, you have to explicit it. So you can write a template `myTemplate` constructor that accept a `myTemplate` pointer, for all possible `myTemplate` types, as follows

```
template <typename U>
myTemplate (myTemplate<U> *, int) { }
```

Obviously you have to avoid the identifier `T` for the internal template to avoid confusion with the external one.